# Token mismatch when changing session driver in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have problem with Laravel CSRF.

I test my code in `native` session driver and everything is OK. but while I change session driver to `redis`, token mismatch error happens.

I also tried to clear cache. but not working.

**this is my form**

```
{{ Form::open(array( 'route' => 'login' )) }}

    {{ Form::text('email') }}

    {{ Form::password('password') }}

    {{ Form::submit('Login') }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

**this is my route**

```
Route::post('login', array('as' => 'login', 'before' => 'csrf', 'uses' => 'UserController@login') );
```

any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that the session is indeed being stored to Redis.

If the session lifetime is set to transient (0 = Expire-on-close) in your configuration, the keystore will be empty and no CSRF token may be matched.

If the data *is* present in Redis, verify the token being sent against the one that is expected using e.g. Firebug to inspect POST form data.