# Token Miss Match When Session driver is Database Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, session

I have a problem when I change the driver session into database, always token miss match when I try login.
I have done some actions like

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache 
php artisankey:generate
```

and also change in config/session.php

```
return [
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),'lifetime' => 120,
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    'encrypt' => false,'files' => 
    'storage_path('framework/sessions'),'connection' => 'mysql',
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'store' => null,
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false);
    'http_only' => true,
];
```

and this error I have

[image]

Comment: Anything in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866404/tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken-php-line-67 able to help?

Comment: @iqbal prabu Please check this link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154990/token-mismatch-when-changing-session-driver-in-laravel-4) i hope its help you

Comment: no hope, i have tried it

Comment: did you implemented {{csrf_field()}} in form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should follow below step wise for set SESSION_DRIVER as database

1- your .env file

**# file = .env in your project root**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=testdb
DB_USERNAME=db_user
DB_PASSWORD=secret_pass

SESSION_DRIVER=database
```

**Note** the DB_CONNECTION setting here that you will need in next step.

2- update config/session.php file Where connection param should hold the string you used for DB_CONNECTION in .env file

**# file = config/session.php**

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),
'connection' => 'mysql', // this is from DB_CONNECTION in .env file
```

3- generate sessions table

```
php artisan session:table
```

// run the migration !!! very very important

```
php artisan migrate
```

4- if for some reason you decided to create the table manually without using migration , use this SQL. This is very important step, a wrong table will result in all kinds of problems. Primarily do not make the mistake of creating a table manually with id column as bigint as usual, session table is different.
`SQL` for sessions table that you should run if you wanna create manually

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sessions`;
create table sessions
(
  id varchar(255) not null,
  user_id int(10) unsigned null,
  ip_address varchar(45) null,
  user_agent text null,
  payload text not null,
  last_activity int not null,
  constraint sessions_id_unique
  unique (id)
)
```

Please check i think this info help for you !!!