# Csrf token issue with scaling

Tags: php, laravel, docker, scale, csrf

I have scaled my application to 3 different servers that use common mysql and redis service. Than I have set session and cache driver to my redis (they are working fine). But I still get token mismatch error. Did anyone solve this problem without turning off CSRF protection?
I`m using Docker by the way.

Comment: Maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154990/token-mismatch-when-changing-session-driver-in-laravel-4

Comment: If that thread doesn't help, post your `docker-compose` file

Answer (score 1):

`php artisan cache:clear` helped. Maybe this is required in all cases, when you change some important settings in .env file